# Having trouble adding a textfield every time a key is pressed in the previous textfield

Tags: jquery, html

I have just started out but i really like using jquery and it's been easy finding answers on other questions on here but now im stuck with this one. I currently have it set to alert:pressed, but i have tried using append in order to add a text field when a key is pressed but i keep coming up with errors.

It should add a new texfield under the original texfield when a user enters a key.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <input type="text" name="keydown" id="keypress" />




    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#keypress").keydown(function () {

                alert("pressed");


        });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried to use that was giving you errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your current textbox, then use event delegation as well:

```
<input type="text" name="keydown" id="keypress" class="textboxpress" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('keydown', '.textboxpress', function () {
        $(this).after("<input type='text' class='textboxpress' />");
    });
});
```

This will append a new textbox right after the focus'd box. If you have a specific container you want to append to, replace `$(this)` with your container selector, and replace `after` with `append`

http://jsfiddle.net/kGwpk/1/

Comment: That was quick, Thanks tymeJV. Would there be a way to make the new textfield run the same function?

Comment: Check out PXL's answer, it's better :D. In short, you'll need to use event delegation.

Comment: @user2506767 -- I've also updated this answer -- it does what you need now.